# Erro android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line

Tags: java, android-fragment

observem a mensagem de erro!

```
2020-01-03 16:37:48.091 27513-27513/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.resource.listfragment, PID: 27513
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.resource.listfragment/com.resource.listfragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.resource.listfragment:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in com.resource.listfragment:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.resource.listfragment:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in com.resource.listfragment:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.resource.listfragment:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.resource.listfragment.ListProdutosFragments that is not a Fragment
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:538)
        at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:53)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3553)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6948)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:438)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3324)
        at com.resource.listfragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-01-03 16:37:48.091 27513-27513/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
        ... 31 more
2020-01-03 16:37:48.110 27513-27513/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27513 SIG: 9
```

Informa que o erro está nessa classe.

```
package com.resource.listfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ListProdutosFragments.OnItemClick {

    private static final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

    private DescProdutosFragments textFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textFrag = (DescProdutosFragments) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(Alimento alimento) {
        textFrag.setText(String.format("O preço do %s é %s", alimento.getNome(), nf.format(alimento.getPreco())));
    }
}
```

Mais precisamente nessa linha.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Esse é meu arquivo XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_list"
        android:name="com.resource.listfragment.ListProdutosFragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_text"
        android:name="com.resource.listfragment.DescProdutosFragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Qual seria a sugestão para corrigir o problema?

Comment: O xml da activity está mal formado.

Comment: acabei de postar meu xml @DaviAragao poderia dar uma olhada?

Comment: `Trying to instantiate a class com.resource.listfragment.ListProdutosFragments that is not a Fragment` -- O erro está informando que a classe `ListProdutosFragments` não é um `Fragment`

Comment: Nossa cara, você conseguiu me ajudar, muito obrigado mesmo, eu coloquei a importação errada. valeu mesmo @AndréRibeiro

Comment: eu tinha colocado esse import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment e na verdade era para ser esse import android.app.ListFragment;

Comment: Não se esqueça de adicionar uma resposta explicando qual era o problema e como resolveu. Dessa forma quem cair aqui com o mesmo erro vai saber o que é e como resolver (fica mais claro que deixar nos comentários).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi no ato de importar o pacote correto, eu tinha importado esse pacote.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e ficou assim!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o pacote certo é esse!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que coloquei o pacote certo funcionou perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]